# What do these multiple wires go to out of the ceiling from where I took the ceiling fan down

Tags: light-fixture, ceiling, ceiling-fan

Took down a ceiling fan in a modular home in my kids bedroom, I’ve changed out a few ceiling fans before, I have never seen this. What are these wires for and how would I hook up a light that has 3 wires(black, white and ground)?

[image]

Comment: where was the fan conected ? do you have fan speed switch ?

Comment: @ knowitall there is only one possible connection point neutral or whiteto the 2 whites and black single to the fan or light black or hot wire

Answer (score 2):

The two whites twisted together are your neutrals.  One comes from the panel and one goes to another light/outlet.

The blacks plus the white is your hot/power.  The white becomes the hot going to the switch, the other two blacks same as your neutrals above.

The single black is the switched hot.  Comes from the switch.

And the bare is is your ground.

Comment: So where do I put the single black in a light fixture that has only a black, white, and ground?

Comment: Black to single black, white to  the two whites.  Leave the blacks plus white as they are.

Comment: So I wouldn’t use the black and white wires twisted together correct? Because I’m not putting another ceiling fan up, just a light?

Comment: The group of black and white wires twisted together are just intermediate connections continuing on to other locations. You would never hook anything up directly to them, neither fan nor light nor anything else.

Answer (score 1):

The whites are the neutrals you would use this point to connect a new fan or light neutral. One is from the panel one is going to another receptacle or device.

The 2 blacks and a white are the hot’s one from the panel one going to a receptacle or another device

The cable with the black wire nutted this is your hot for another fan or light this goes to the switch with the white that is a switch leg and should be marked especially at the switch with a black or other non white, gray or green but that will be the only cable in that box if a single so many electricians don’t mark them.